# Raspberry Pi stuck on script at startup

Tags: linux, bash, raspberry-pi

I wanted to have my Raspberry Pi update the system clock from a GPS on start up but now something has gone wrong and I can't login. 
I created a bash script that calls 'sudo -i' and a few other gpsd related instructions. I pointed the /etc/profile towards the script. If I Ctrl+C to get to a prompt I get root access but the directories are listing nothing when I use the 'ls' command. If I exit from root I get stuck again. I figure that if I could delete the bash script the problem would go away but I don't know how to view that partition of the SD card on a PC. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I solved the problem. There is a ext4 partition editor called ExtFS for Windows. You can view and edit an ext4 partition easily in this program. You can download it [here](http://www.paragon-software.com/home/extfs-windows/index.html).